# Solving PDE via Fourier transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

I need to find the solution to this equation using the Fourier transform:
$$ \partial_t f(x,t) = t^2\partial_{xx}^2 f(x,t) -t \partial_x f(x,t)+\delta(t)\delta(x^2-1)$$ with initial condition $f(x,-1) = 0$
I was a little bit startled because the initial solution is given at $t=-1$ and not at $t=0$.
I followed this procedure:
for $t>0$ the equation becomes (due to the Dirac delta properties):
$$ \partial_t f(x,t) = t^2\partial_{xx}^2 f(x,t) -t \partial_x f(x,t) $$
Using the Fourier transform, and omitting some easy calculations, I obtain the following ODE:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\hat{f}(k,t) = -k^2t^2\hat{f}(k,t)-ikt\hat{f}(k,t) $$
The standard solution yields:
$\hat{f}(k,t) = C(k)e^{-(\frac{t^3}{3}k^2+ik\frac{t^2}{2})}$
I find the coefficient $C(k)$ in the following way:
$$\hat{f}(k,0) = C(k)e^0 \Rightarrow C(k) = \hat{f}(k,0)e^{-1}$$
Hence we finally get:
$$ \hat{f}(k,t) = \hat{f}(k,0)e^{-1} e^{-(\frac{t^3}{3}k^2+ik\frac{t^2}{2})}$$
Now the solution tells me that $\hat{f}(k,t) = \hat{f}(k,0) e^{-(\frac{t^3}{3}k^2+ik\frac{t^2}{2})}$ without the $e^{-1}$ term: so my first question is: where am I making a mistake? The method I followed for solving that ODE is the same as ever, and it works as far as I can remember.
Now another problem arose while solving this: I can't seem to find the initial solution $f(x,0)$. I need it because, without it, I wouldn't be able to use the Fourier inversion theorem:
$$\hat{f}(k,0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int f(x',0)e^{-ikx'}dx' $$
I could solve for $t>1$ but that Delta term wouldn't vanish which would make the equation much more complicated. Is there some kind of way of *extending* the initial solution from $t=-1$ to $t=0$? I thought that maybe the initial solution could somehow be $0$ not only at $t=-1$, but in some wider interval $[-1-\epsilon, -1+\epsilon]$. Nevertheless, this would probably work if $\epsilon \to 0$ and this doesn't seem to help me at all.
Well this is as far as I could go. Hope someone can enlighten me a bit more on how to solve this. The procedure I followed seems to be the right one. The solution somehow affirms that it can be easily seen that $f(x,0) = \delta(x^2-1)$ but I can't seem to figure how it does unfortunately.

Comment: Well, that's kind of embarrassing. I might have to pull out the I am totally exhausted card. Thank  you @Gonçalo for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $t<0$, the PDE also reduces to
$$
\partial_t f(x,t) = t^2\partial_{xx}^2 f(x,t) -t \partial_x f(x,t). \tag{1}
$$
Notice that $f(x,t)=0$ satisfies $(1)$ and the initial condition $f(x,-1)=0$, hence it is the solution to the PDE in the interval $-1\leq t<0$. Now, integrating both sides of
$$
\partial_t f(x,t) = t^2\partial_{xx}^2 f(x,t) -t \partial_x f(x,t)+\delta(t)\delta(x^2-1) \tag{2}
$$
from $t=-\epsilon$ to $t=+\epsilon$, we find
$$
f(x,+\epsilon)=f(x,-\epsilon)+\int_{-\epsilon}^{+\epsilon}[t^2\partial_{xx}^2 f(x,t) -t \partial_x f(x,t)]\,dt+\delta(x^2-1).\tag{3}
$$
Since $f(x,-\epsilon)=0$, and the integral on the RHS of $(3)$ vanishes in the limit $\epsilon\to 0^+$, we end up with $f(x,0^+)=\delta(x^2-1)$.

Comment: Could you explain a bit further: I don't get how $f(x,t) = 0, t \in [-1,0[$ represents the solution. I still believe that would work only for $t = -1$, since we don't know anything about f(x,t) for $t \ne 1$. The rest is ok but the first passage still seems obscure

Comment: My problem is only with the sentence starting with since. I cant seem to understand how to justify it? Did you use the fact that The null solution is obviously a trivial solution of (1)

Comment: Well I was just making sure not to make any bold assumptions on the nature of the solution. Since my mathematical means are nowhere near great, I tend to oversimplify things too much and this leads to mistakes. Again thank you for the explanation. The integration trick seems very useful, I'll surely make good use of it